# RecyclerView con secciones y datos de Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Hola estoy trabajando en una app, en ella tengo que llenar un recyclerview con datos de Firebase, lo cual he logrado hacer con el adaptador e informacion que mismo firebase [proporciona](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). Ahora lo que quiero hacer es llenar un recyclerview con los datos de firebase pero que tenga secciones las cuales serian el padre que alojan los datos en firebase, estoy un poco perdido con esto, y creo que es en el adaptador del Recyclerview donde no se como hacerlo, espero me puedan ayudar.

Aca una imagen de lo que quiero hacer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta todo explicado en el link que proporcionaste, ¿lo intentaste?, ¿cual es el problema?

Comment: Tienes que intentar como menciona rnd, en base a eso preguntar dudas, no entiendo el adaptador que deseas tener, en una vista quieres un header con Section1 y abajo "info-01-info" y "info-01-info"???. Puedes dar un vista a esta pregunta:  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6552/recycleview-simple-en-android

Comment: Asi es, en los headers irían como quien dice el nombre del grupo de datos de firebase, seria como mostrarlos jerárquicamente, como dije yo lo he hecho pero mostrando solo todos los valores del ultimo nivel de firebase, pero no he conseguido agregar las secciones con los nombres obteniéndose de firebase

Answer (score 1):

El adaptador incluido en la librería Firebase UI, esta diseñado para manejar un tipo de dato. Se encarga de la sincronización serialización y de agregarlo al adapter.

Manejar 2 niveles de datos distintos (en tu caso, titulo y seccion) en un mismo adapter no es imposible, pero requiere de una extensa modificación del adapter y el de firebase UI ya es de por si bastante complejo.

No es un patrón típico para el [diseño en Android](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html) tener 2 niveles jerárquicos en una misma lista, te recomendaría que utilices alguna de las estrategias en el link (tabs es el más común). Si estás determinado a hacerlo en formato de lista te recomiendo utilizar un "acordeon" como por ejemplo el que implementa [esta librería](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view).